# Stumped by timeout issue

Tags: .net, wcf, timeout

Upon clicking a button in the browser, a .net web app on server A runs a WCF that calls a stored procedure on database server B. Server A then processes the results before sending back a response to the browser.

If the stored proc takes less than 60 seconds, server A gets the results and processes them (can take several minutes), and the browser gets a response back. If the stored procedure takes longer than 60 seconds, server A will still get the results and process them (can take several minutes), but the browser never gets a response back. We've set every timeout value we can think of. Any ideas?

There is a firewall between servers, but I'm told the default timeout is 30 minutes.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the timeout config? (in server and client)

Comment: We've increased timeouts on client and server with no luck. Happens in both IE and Firefox.

Comment: want to try Wireshark and see whats going on on TCP level?

Comment: I haven't used Wireshark, but I have used Fiddler which shows no response coming back from server A when the process on server B (called by A) takes longer than 60 seconds. Like I said, B is still returning data to A because A processes that data successfully.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the receive timeout. By default, it is one minute.

Comment: Umm, the default seems to be [10 minutes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I've increased the receive timeout but it didn't fix it.

What's strange is that when just the processing on PART of the process (on B) takes over 60 seconds the browser doesn't get a response back. The whole thing can take 4+ minutes and it works fine, as long as the part on B takes less than 60 seconds. Even when the part on B takes over 60 seconds, the whole process on the server side will finish. Does that make sense?